# How to set the color of the letters of the file-properties window, in windows 8/8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, colors, themes, color-theme

What I need to change is the color of the black letters in the property window:

[image]

I think that I need to add or modify a key here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors
```

Or here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors
```

In [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2007/08/06/personalizing-the-desktop-on-a-windows-server-2008-server-core-install/) publication are documented all (or I think that are all) the possible customization values, this way I've found and modified the background color of the properties window, but I can't find any value related to set the color of the letters inside the properties window, I would like to set the letters to a light color (white).

I would like to automate this task via Registry, but this can be done via Registry?, if not, what other solution exist?

> UPDATE

This is the result that I expect, and I need to do this without enabling the `HighContast` parameter in the `.Theme` file, I know that I need to modify the `.msstyle` file, but the 3rd party theme that I'm using is not mine so I don't know how to edit the file and where is the value to change the textcolor:

[image]

Comment: Changing `Registry` key values is risky task. Better to change the theme.

Comment: @udaykiran pulipati I'm trying to find out the way to modify a .msstyle file but seems impossible, all what I've found is this tool which never has been released: http://tabletosconcept.deviantart.com/art/MsStyler-Progress-03-06-375649072 + http://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=28246&start=25

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value you're looking for is `ButtonText`
It has a type of `REG_SZ` (string value)
You should take a look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24609/create-a-windows-7-theme-pack-from-scratch/) to see how you can achieve this by creating a custom theme from scratch.

However, make sure that your theme is a `HighContrast` one or else the color change won't take effect. Here's a sample theme that sets the `ButtonText` value to `0 0 255` which makes everything look Blue.

```
[Theme]
DisplayName=Sample Theme

[Control Panel\Colors]
ButtonText=0 0 255

[Control Panel\Desktop]
TileWallpaper=0
WallpaperStyle=10

[VisualStyles]
Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\AeroLite.msstyles
ColorStyle=NormalColor
Size=NormalSize
HighContrast=1

[MasterThemeSelector]
MTSM=DABJDKT
```

Save that as a ".theme" file and apply it by double clicking on the file.
[image]

Comment: I never thought I could fix this, my eyes will be eternally grateful with you :).

Comment: Really is not wha I'm lookin for... If I change that value then it affects also to a lot of my applications also to StackOverflow pages, the buttons of SO are just empty in high-constrast... this is so ugly, please could you tell me how to do it with a non-highcontrast theme?

Comment: all the software installed on my computer looks really bad in high-contrast and my eyes cant more using this :(. I just want to change the color of the letters inside the properties page like others 3rd party themes can do without needing to set High-contrast.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know of a way to change that without enabling high contrast mode. UXTheme Patcher might help though
http://www.windowsxlive.net/uxtheme-multi-patcher/

Comment: I'm already using the UXTheme Patcher :( thanks for your help